# Wordpress. Contact Form 7. Не всегда приходит телефон

Tags: php, wordpress, ajax, contact-form7

Отправка формы производится на несколько email адресов. Проблема в том, что у меня приходят все данные, которые заполняет пользователь, а вот у заказчика почему-то отсутствует поле с телефоном клиента. Форма одна и тоже, поле является обязательным. Проблему найти очень сложно, потому что у меня всё работает отлично. Причем заказчик не использует никаких почтовых программ, всё проверяется в браузере по адресу gmail так же, как и я.
Ошибки и т.д. отсутствуют, все данные через xhr я вижу и они отправляются (что логично, данные же ко мне итак приходят)

Comment: Скорее всего Вам приходят РАЗНЫЕ письма. См шаблоны. Или маловероятно, но возможно - какой-то антивирус или сервис чистит тело письма у заказчика.

Comment: @SeVlad Форма одна, проверял раз 20. Уже давно эта проблема. Так если бы письмо было пустое - ещё ладно. А так нет только почты. То есть одного поля из всех

Comment: Добавьте третью тестовую почту и посмотрите что туда приходит.

Comment: Как проверял? Добавь текст в шаблон письма и перепроверь.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего в шаблоне письма, что приходит заказчику, не верно указана переменная что хранит в себе телефон. проверьте шаблон

Comment: Так мне же это письмо приходит с телефоном, там почты указаны через запятую.

Comment: Попробуйте отправить ещё на пару почтовых ящиков то же письмо. У всех будет схожая проблема? Может фильтры какого то определённого почтовика шалят